# MySQL how to quickly match a column and update?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

```
 SSN  NAME PT1 PT2 PT3

 0002 Abby  12  14 15
```

Now I am writing a procedure that taking input with ssn, pt name and a new value. Lets say I can match with ssn 0002 and I need to find PT2 to update the value to be 28.

I am quite confused since the update format is update/set/where. However, how can I match the column name with the input without brutally check them one by one? I certainly can do

```
IF ptname = PT1 then ... else IF ptname = PT2 then ...
```

However the code would be tedious. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what your desired output is.  Your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: @Tim  Lets say input: SSN = 0002, ptname = PT3, value = 28.  So that after the update I would like to get a row: 0002 Abby 12 14 28

Comment: Show a sample input table _and_ the desired output.  You are speaking in language which most SQL folks would find strange.

Answer (score 0):

Create your sql in the variable

```
DECLARE @mySQL nVARCHAR(4000)

SET @mySQL = 'UPDATE tableName SET '+ @strColumn + ' = ' + @strValue 

EXECUTE sys.sp_executesql @mySQL, N'@strColumn VARCHAR(12), @strValue VARCHAR(12)',strColumn ,strValue
```